# Trivial Cohomology Group->Lower-Dimensional Homotopy?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homology-cohomology

Calculating the (de-Rham) cohomology of a tee connector ([Picture](http://www.google.de/imgres?safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3ade%3aofficial&biw=1337&bih=640&tbm=isch&tbnid=Jv2C-y4MlAEfCM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/358543764/T_connector_pipe/showimage.html&docid=q4d-EAduEcnCMM&imgurl=http://i00.i.aliimg.com/photo/v0/358543764/T_connector_pipe.jpg&w=400&h=320&ei=SBn0Uv7YAdHLswak74HgDw&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=553&page=2&start=18&ndsp=24&ved=0CMwBEK0DMCY)), I got  $H^0=R,H^1=R^2,H^2=0$.

Furthermore, just from looking at it, I assume the tee connector is homotopic to a circle with an arc connecting two antipodal points.

Is it always true that an $n$-dimensional manifold with trivial cohomology groups for $k_0< k \leq n$ is homotopic to a $k_0$-dimensional manifold?

Comment: I'm a bit confused - the example you write is not homotopic to a $k_0$-dimensional manifold.  In fact, there is no 1 dimensional manifold with the same de Rham cohomology groups as you listed: a connected (because $H^0 = \mathbb{R}$) 1-d manifold is either $(0,1))$ or $S^1$, so $\dim H^1 \leq 1$.

Comment: You are right, shouldn't ask questions late at night. Would there be a topological sensible formulation of my idea though? Is the circle with an arc something to work with, i.e. something with a better topological description? I'm no topologist at all

Answer (score 6):

No; for instance, there are acyclic spaces (i.e. with vanishing cohomology in dimension $>0$) which are not contractible (i.e. not homotopic to a $0$-dimensional manifold). For instance, the Poincaré sphere with a point deleted from it is acyclic, but it is not contractible because it has nonvanishing $\pi_1$. (The $\pi_1$ of the non-punctured Poincaré sphere is the binary isocahedral group of order $120$, whose abelianization is trivial. Therefore, $H^1$ vanishes, and the cohomology is concentrated in degree $0$ and in the top degree $3$. Deleting a point then kills the top cohomology.)